# Jquery UI Accordion, not refreshing after loading content

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-ui-accordion

In a wordpress site, I have loading side categories and category content.  Now I the content is setup with the accordion format.  So you have an idea of what I've done here's the [link](http://perutravelsolutions.com/utp/admision/) to what I'm dealing with. My problem is as you can see that when I click on a category on the left, first time the accordion works, but when i click on another category it messes up completely.  I have tried several things and nothing doing..here's what I have so far:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.categorias li').click(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $('#subtitle').html($(this).find('#title').html()); 
    $('#acc').html($('#' + id + '-content').html()).accordion({
            autoheight: false

       });

});
```

I have also tried:

```
 $('#acc').html($('#' + id + '-content').html())
 $('#acc').accordion(.accordion({ clearStyle: true });
```

But as you can see nothing doing. Any ideas?

Comment: Your Javascript return an error : `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of null` main.js:29. Try to fix it first :)

Comment: not sure how to fix that, but didn't think that played against the accordion working

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not help you simplify, but i thought i would throw out how i handle accordion menus. it collapses between each  tag...

```
<div id="right_area">
    <h3><a href="#">New Client Entry:</a></h3>
        <div id="sub_cat">
            <h4><a href="#">this is sub:</a></h4>
            <div>yo yo</div>
            <h4><a href="#">this is sub:</a></h4>
            <div>yo yo</div>
        </div>
    <h3><a href="#">Old Client Entry:</a></h3>
    <div>hello there</div>
</div>



$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#right_area").accordion({
        collapsible: true,
        active: false,
        clearStyle: true
    });
  });


    $("#sub_cat").accordion({
        collapsible: true,
        active: false,
        clearStyle: true
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LSg36/2/